# Circle search algorythm

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to create an algorythm that is capable of finding circles in a graph using graphx and scala.
What I'm thinking about is loading all vertexIDs into an array, create a loop that creates a second array, filled with the vertexes that can be reached, then do the same with that array and so on.
Basically, it'd look the following:
`StartArray -> 1AwayNodes -> 2AwayNodes -> 3AwayNodes` and so on. For example, a triangle would be if a node is in its own "3AwayNodes" array, a 'square' if it's in its own "4AwayNodes" array.
I have my graph, and thought about the following:

```
graph.vertices.foreach{v => (vertexIDarray :+ v.VertexId)}
```

but it says "value VertexId is not a member of (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)"

I am extremely new to scala and would be thankful if anyone could just point me to any place where these functions are explained and not just used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so digging deeper into the issue I came to the conclusion that

```
graph.vertices.foreach{v => (vertexIDarray :+ v._1)}
```

should do what I intended to achieve
If it in fact the correct solution I'll be picking this as answer for future reference for other newbies